# How to send image in Restful Jax-rs

Tags: jax-rs

I want to send an image from java server (Restful Jax-rs).
My client is Android.

```
@GET
public Response getUserImage() {
byte[] image =new byte[1024];
return Response.ok(image, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).header("content-attachment; filename=image_from_server.png") .build();
```

But here one download box is coming.
So I want to download without download box, when I run the request URL on browser it should open automatically.
Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

I believe that's because you specified `application/octet-stream`.

I think you should use `image/jpeg` or `image/png`.

```java
@GET
@Produces({"image/png"})
public Response getUserImage() {

    final byte[] image = ...;
    // say your image is png?

    return Response.ok().entity(new StreamingOutput(){
        @Override
        public void write(OutputStream output)
           throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
           output.write(image);
           output.flush();
        }
    }).build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can encode the image with base 64 encoding, wrap the base 64 encoded string in xml or json and send that over rest. On the rest client extract the base 64 encoded string and decode it to get the final image. This preserves all the file meta data as well and but the only down side is 30% increase in image size.
I have tried the same with Restlet rest api, am pretty sure its possible over JAX-RS as well.